# Prove that limit of a sequence is dependent on limit of all components

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having trouble with [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sequence_by_Components_(Euclidean_Space)).

I can't understand the last step, or where the square root of n comes from and why it multiplies epsilon.

The book from my university does a proof which also has that square root of n. It's in the page 23 of [this book](http://glaroton.ungs.edu.ar/calculo.pdf) (35 in the pdf file). Can someone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|a_{ij}-a_i|< \epsilon$, you have that $$|x_j-x|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \left|a_{ij}-a_i\right|^2 < \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon^2 = n\epsilon^2.$$ Then take the square of both sides to get the result $$\left|x_j-x\right|<\epsilon\sqrt{n}.$$